# How Can I Find the Drive Mount Point of an Arbitrary Directory?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I'm interested in finding the mount point of an arbitrary directory on my external hard drive for a program that I'm writing.

If my drive is mounted on /media/sarah/drive and this folder is on /media/sarah/drive/Snapshots how would I be able to use the command line to get /media/sarah/drive from it?

`findmnt -n` and `mount` both seem helpful, but I can't seem to use either of them to get the desired output.

Comment: Does `findmnt -T /media/sarah/drive/Snapshots` give you the information you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df` for that:

```
$ df --output=target /media/sarah/drive/Snapshots
Mounted on
/media/sarah/drive
```

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have thought to use `df`!